# JQuery Toggle with sliding effect or similar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#MyLink').click(function(){
     $('#DivA').toggle();
     $('#DivB').toggle(); 
  });
});
</script>
```

I just need to add some sliding to it of some other effect so that you can tell that it's actually swapping from one div to another.

Comment: And ... what is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the slidetoggle function

```
$(function(){
  $('#MyLink').click(function(){
     $('#DivA').slideToggle();
     $('#DivB').slideToggle(); 
  });
});
```

You can also experiment with passing a duration to toggle—this will add a sliding effect to the element you're toggling

```
$(function(){
  $('#MyLink').click(function(){
     $('#DivA').toggle('slow');
     $('#DivB').toggle('slow'); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#MyLink').click(function(){
     $('#DivA').slideToggle();
     $('#DivB').slideToggle(); 
  });
});
</script>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wE5Rh/)

Comment: slideToggle is not smooth at all

Comment: slideToggle is as smooth as butter http://jsfiddle.net/wE5Rh/. Include code if there is something wrong with your page